# Python Stream Kafka - Cannot see any stream data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Even after many tries I cannot see any message neither on the console nor written to file.

Below my code :

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","ipaddress:9092")\
    .option("subscribe","mysql-server-1.inventory.customers")\
    .option("partition.assignment.strategy", "range") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")\
    .load()#.

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

print(df.printSchema())
print("Streaming : {}".format(df.isStreaming))

ds = df.writeStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ipaddress:9092")\
    .option("topic", "mysql-server-1.inventory.customers")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://ipaddress:9000/user/xxxx/check")\
    .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

Note :

1. topic at writeStream already try use another name
2. format at writeStream already try use console with append, update and complete. Also already try with parquet for write to file
3. When print ds.lastProgress() get NoneType

Comment: Kafka to Kafka? Why not use Kafka Streams for this?

Comment: And you definitely shouldn't produce back to the input topic, otherwise you get an infinite processing loop and can fill the kafka disks

Comment: @cricket_007, Thank you. Its work now